# gi.overrides.GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf to Gtk.Widget

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

I am loading, resizing and placing an image like this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

logo = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file('logo.jpg')
logo = logo.scale_simple(100, 100, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)

box_outer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
box_outer.add(logo)
```

The message I get is `TypeError: argument widget: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got gi.overrides.GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf`.

How do I convert the Pixbuf to a Widget?

Answer (score 0):

`Gtk.Image` is a widget that can display the pixbuf.